# C# & ASP.NET : SqlCommand won't insert record but preserving autoincrement id

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm writing a SQL command to insert new record into a SQL Server database using an ASP.NET website, but it's not working, although it's preserving the id of an auto-increment column.

When the auto-increment value is 5, and then I try to insert a new row using Management Studio, it does insert the record with id=7.

Thanks to anyone who tells me what I'm doing wrong here

Here is the code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

try
{
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Bill values (@car, @date, @client, @speedometer, @employee, @notes)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", carid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", txt_bill_date.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client", cmb_client_name.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@speedometer", txt_car_gas.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee", cmb_emp.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", txt_notes.Value);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 bill_id from Bill order by bill_id DESC";

    DataTable inserted = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(inserted);

    if (inserted.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        billid = inserted.Rows[0]["bill_id"].ToString();
        contractid.Values["id"] = inserted.Rows[0]["bill_id"].ToString();

        Response.Redirect("BillContracts.aspx");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "swal('خطأ', '" + ex.Message + "', 'error')", true);
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the parameters and ensure they are not empty.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to be able to know what you're doing wrong. However, here are some tips to make troubleshooting your code easier: 1)  specify the column names in your `INSERT INTO` statement 2) use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue` 3) `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected so there isn't really a need to perform a select statement on the data that was just inserted into the database

Comment: If an identity column's value is being "burned", it means that the insert itself is failing, usually because you're violating a constraint or rolling back a transaction. You need to catch the exception and report the error message. Right now, there's not enough actionable information. **Needs debugging details**

Comment: tell me what do i have to provide more and i'll update the question.....

Comment: i'm retrieving the last id because i want to pass it to another form when Redirecting ....

Comment: I just told you what you need to do: catch the exception and report the error message.

Comment: thanks for the reply , i updated the code , i'm using try and catch ...

Comment: Right, but you're not telling us what the error message is!

Comment: If you don't specify the column names during an insert, they are inserted positionally. The first one gets inserted into the first column, which probably is your autoincrement column. Hence the need to specify the column names in the statement. One doesn't specify a value for an autoincrement column.

Comment: user9938 is probably right, but without the error message, it's just a guess. Add the error message to the post. Use the `>` line prefix to give it quoted formatting so it can be picked out easily. And on the subject of formatting, take some time to format the code. The last edit was worse than it was in the first place.

Comment: @madreflection it's not thowing any exception

Comment: Are you certain about that?  Did you put a breakpoint on the `{` in the catch block? Writing a client script in an catch block is hacky at best, a very bad, lazy pattern.

Comment: @user9937  , actually i just tried specifying column names but nothing changed

Comment: @user9937 the first column is a foreign key to another table

Comment: Instead of little tidbits in the comments, **put the schema in the post**. Put ***everything*** that's relevant in the body of the post.

Comment: You need to post more code. What is `cmd`? What database are you connecting to?

Comment: @madreflection sorry for this man but this is my second question on Stackoverflow ...

Comment: That has nothing to do with the issue here. You're presenting a problem to people who have never seen your code and are wholly unfamiliar with it. You couldn't expect someone to help you in person with the same level of information, either. The difference is that, in person, someone could look at the parts of the project they need to see. We can't do that, so you have to do that for us. You're not doing that. You're trickling information in at a minimal pace. That doesn't help us, but worse, **it doesn't help you**.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the inconvenience guys
your advice of putting a break point on the catch saved my day
the problem was with the columns type
apparently be mistake i added an int column for a string value
i apologize again if i didn't do this right

Comment: What you have to ask yourself now is why, when told to catch the exception, you didn't put the breakpoint there. That should be automatic.

Comment: Writing alert scripts in the response is hacky at best, and you should avoid that practice entirely.

Comment: @madreflection thanks for the advice,would you please suggest a better method ?

Comment: No. WebForms is outdated. It's been over a decade since I've used it, but I remember seeing it and being appalled by how bad it was. My advice would be not to use WebForms in the first place.

Comment: i'll consider that , but for now it's too late because i'm almost done with the project , i appreciate your help man ..